# How to use underscore in a variable

Tags: graphics, captions, underscore

I have a variable x which takes different names including underscore, for instance 1_10. 
Later, I want to use that variable as the title of a picture:

```
\caption{\x}
```

However I can't do that because latex only accept it as a formula, it is:

```
\caption{$\x$}
```

But in this case the result is different than I want. Is there any way to display the variable as it is?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
\begin{document}

\def \datasets {18/1_10,18/3_10,19/1_6,19/1_9,23/1_4,23/5_4,26/1_6,26/4_7}
\graphicspath{{/home/alvaroeg/SemesterProject/Figures/}}

\foreach \x/\cyc in \datasets
{   
            \begin{figure}[h]
                \includegraphics[width= \textwidth]{dataset\x /XY/dataset\x _cyc_\cyc _ XY_fixed_image.jpg}
            \caption{Dataset\x .\cyc }
            \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: "But in this case the result is different than I want." What is the result and what is your desired result. Please be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: The usual approach `\newcommand*{\x}{1\_10}` works fine for me. Please try this.

Comment: Here are some options: `x\textunderscore10 x\_10 $\mathrm{x}_{10}$ \texttt{x\textunderscore10}`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, but it didn't work. The idea is that I can use that variable for each iteration of the for loop. I included the code I'm using.

When I said that the result is different than I want I meant that if you write something like $1_10$, it is understood that you want the 1 after the underscore as subindices.

Comment: `\caption{Dataset\x .\detokenize\expandafter{\cyc}}`

Comment: Don't do that with file names, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in your preamble, you solve the issue by doing

```
\caption{Dataset\x.\detokenize\expandafter{\cyc}}
```

because this will “stringify” the expansion of `\cyc`.

If you don't or can't use `T1`, then

```
\caption{\texttt{Dataset\x.\detokenize\expandafter{\cyc}}}
```

will work as well.